# Javacript calculation not functioning in EDIT MODAL, values loaded from database

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have gross amount, % to be less and the net amount. I have ADD modal with the codes below that is working, but when it comes to the EDIT modal, it's not working. values loaded from the database.

```
<select class="w3-select w3-border w3-small" id ="vtpercent" name="vtpercent" onchange="calculatevtnet(this.value)" required>
       <option value="" disabled selected>Select Percent</option>
       <option value="0.01">1%</option>
       <option value="0.02">2%</option>
</select>
--------------
```

---

```
<script>
             function calculatevtnet(val){
              
                var vtgross = document.getElementById('vtgross');
                var vtnet= vtgross - (vtgross / 1.12 * 0.05) - (vtgross / 1.12 * val);
                var vtnetdec = vtnet.toFixed(2);
                var divobj = document.getElementById('vtnet');
                divobj.value = vtnetdec;
             }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need more context for your question but here i could see `var vtgross = document.getElementById('vtgross');` this element is in modal so may be when you are editing the modal the function `calculatevtnet()` is called but modal didn't loaded yet so js is able to get it so try do it when modal completely loaded.

if not then share your whole code so that we can help you thanks